# How to execute VBA code without opening Visual Basic editor

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently developing a program to read Excel.

However, I have a few validation points that need to be validated in both Java and Excel. Hence, I want my Excel to validate some simple logic for me on Excel file.

I am going to distribute my Excel file which includes my VBA code, How does my user execute the validation code?

I don't want my user to open the Visual Basic Editor and run it - is there any simple way to do that?

I found that there is a way to insert button, is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options:
- you can make a button like you said
- you can ask the user to execute the macro via the developer tab
- you can make a macro that executes upon an action, for instance sheet activation, cell change, opening a file, ...

Comment: thanks ! can you teach me how to applied upon cell change, i am ok with tutorial URL..

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Answer (score 2):

Yes like Lambik allready wrote there are a lot of solutions.
VBA has a lot of objects and there are a lot of events

[image]

In this picture you can see your objects, I chose the Object Worksheet, when you add a form or a button you can find these objects here as well and there are a lot like workbook, worksheets, input-fields, cells and so one.

When you have your Objects chosen on the left side you can chose the event in the right.

When you add a button and double click on it or right click and go on edit code, it will be the click-event but you can chose the double-click event aswell.

In the screen above we had the object worksheet:

[image]

When you now chose the event activate, you will get the basic sub method.
The code inside will be execute, when you will activate a worksheet.
For better understanding a little exsample:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
      MsgBox "You just activated " & ActiveSheet.Name
    End Sub
```

When you only want to do something when a specific worksheet got activated you can ask, which worksheet got activated and only then execute the code you want.

The same way you can use the other objects and events.